# array changes when i change parameter

Tags: c

So i have this code in c.It all works fine until i get to the point to read word again.It gets the new word but also the (*A)[size-1] takes the price of the new word.How do i prevent this?

```
void fuction(char ***A,char ***B,int size)
{
    char word[20],word2[20];
    printf("Type word .\n");
    gets(word);
    while(strcmp(word,"0")!=0)
    {
        printf("Type second word.\n");
        gets(word2);
        printf("%d",size);
        **A=realloc(**A,(size+1)*sizeof(char));
        **B=realloc(**B,(size+1)*sizeof(char));

        (*A)[size-1]=word;
        (*B)[size-1]=word2;

        size++;

        printf("Type another word to add or 0 to exit.\n");//**it all works fine** 
        gets(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw `char ***A` I knew you were in trouble...

Comment: The second trouble maker is `gets`.  Never use it.

Comment: Yes use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Why am I looking at cubic matrixes?

Comment: Posting the code that calls `fuction()` would help in generating good answers.  Without that, there are many guesses.

Comment: A big problem with this code is `size`.  As more data is added, the calling code has no means of knowing how `size` changed.  Suggest passing the address of `size` instead.

Comment: Moe likely code should be `(*A)[size]=word; (*B)[size]=word2;`  (drop -1)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char ***A, char ***B, int *size){
    char word[32], word2[32];

    printf("Type first word.\n");
    scanf("%31s", word);
    while(strcmp(word,"0")!=0){
        printf("Type second word.\n");
        scanf("%31s", word2);
        *A =realloc(*A, (*size+1)*sizeof(char*));
        *B =realloc(*B, (*size+1)*sizeof(char*));
        (*A)[*size]=strdup(word);
        (*B)[*size]=strdup(word2);

        ++*size;

        printf("Type another word to add or 0 to exit.\n");
        scanf("%31s", word);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i, size = 0;
    char **w1, **w2;
    w1 = w2 = NULL;
    function(&w1, &w2, &size);
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%s, %s\n", w1[i], w2[i]);
        free(w1[i]);free(w2[i]);
    }
    free(w1);free(w2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if realloc fails?

Comment: Because it is just a sample(to point out the error) check omitted. It is not the purpose is to provide the code.

Comment: Such as the recovery of failure  I think of separate from the main problem. And emphasize the error by as much as possible close to the code to the original. When too much change the code it becomes unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was that i didnt allocate memory for the words in the array.I added these lines and it worked.Thank you for your answers.

`(*A)[size-1]=(char*) malloc(31);
 (*B)[size-1]=(char*) malloc(31);`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
(*A)[size-1]=word;
(*B)[size-1]=word2;
```

is not what you think it is.

In c, this means you are assigning the address to the first element of the array `word` to `(*A)[size-1]` if you want this to work, provided that you have allocated memory for `(*A)[size-1]` you should do it this way

```
strcpy((*A)[size-1], word);
strcpy((*B)[size-1], word2);
```

You should think about why do you need `char ***`, generally you wont need more than `char **`, and don't use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: No it doesn't, it does what I describe. In fact, when you return from the function, all the data will be gone.

Comment: i have a 2D array in main which i need to reallocate in fuction.thats why i use *** and not **

Comment: when i return from the fuction it just puts 0 at the end of the array because thats why i give as a word to and the fuction.i need it to keep the first word

Comment: @Jenny Then your `**A = realloc(**A, (size+1)*sizeof(char))` is wrong.

Comment: @Jenny I think you need to re-think what you have to ask and ask a new question, including in it the caller function, becase it seems you are very confused on how to do what you want.

Comment: the caller fuction is fuction(&A,&B,size).I just want the (*A)[size-1] not to change when char word does so

Comment: If your `A` is declared as `char **A;` in the caller function then change this `**A=realloc(**A,(size+1)*sizeof(char)); -> *A=realloc(*`A,(size+1)*sizeof(char));` and the same for `B`, and try using a temporary variable to avoid overwriting the pointer with `NULL` in case `realloc` fails, unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: @Jenny did you try it?

Comment: @Jenny post the whole thing if you want help.

Comment: thanks very much for your help.I will do some things differently and if I dont succeed anything i will post again